# Input with list/datalist: Remove dropdown arrow in Chrome version 91

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following Razor/HTML code to generate an input field with a list/datalist:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BarcodeField.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control inputBarcodeField", @name = "edtBarcodeField", @id = "edtBarcodeField", @maxlength = "10", @list = "lastScannedBarcodes" } })
<datalist id="lastScannedBarcodes"></datalist>
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```html
    <input class="form-control inputBarcodeField text-box single-line valid focus" id="edtBarcodeField" list="lastScannedBarcodes" maxlength="10" name="BarcodeField.Value" type="text" value="">
    <datalist id="lastScannedBarcodes"><option value="9900000000"></option></datalist>
```

By default, Chrome puts an arrow into the input box once the datalist gets filled with options. In Chrome 90 and lower I could hide this arrow with the following CSS:

```
/* this is to hide the ugly dropdown arrow for the last scanned barcodes */
.inputBarcodeField::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
}
```

But since Google released Chrome version 91, users are complaining that the arrow came back. I can confirm this.

Chrome 90 (OK!):

[image: Chrome 90 without arrow]

Chrome 91 (**NOT** OK):

[image: Chrome 91 with arrow]

**How to remove this arrow in Chrome 91?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `!important` :

```css
.inputBarcodeField::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control inputFieldGrading inputBarcodeField text-box single-line valid focus" id="edtBarcodeField" list="lastScannedBarcodes" maxlength="10" name="BarcodeField.Value" type="text" value="">
    <datalist id="lastScannedBarcodes"><option value="9900000000"></option></datalist>
```

Comment: So easy. This worked like a charm! (Before, I made a comment that it did not work, but it was a mistake by me.)

Comment: `!important` save my head.

Comment: Thank you so much :D